# Firebase design in order to reduce document read

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My project is like FaceBook, meaning that once a user enters to my app, they can see people posts in a feed.
The question is that if I"m following 30 people and each of them has 5 posts, it means that I need to download for every normal user (for start) 150 documents and this expensive.

Any advice on how to reduce the document reads?

Comment: you can make like one read to all your users and them implement the logic in your app. like: `if(following_list.contains(document.data['user'])) posts_to_show.add(document.data['posts'];` something like this.

Comment: If you want to show all enters of followers you have to read all of them but if you want to show only some amount you can try limitTolast() query.  Also in firebase read counts are not important size of document which you fetch is important. But cannot say anything without to see your db structure.

Comment: Vitor: but every user has different followers,  so I'm not sure how one read to all users will help

Comment: @AsiB could you share your firebase structure? it would be better to understand and help you

Comment: It's a recipe for pain to design data to reduce the number of reads.  You will have problems in the future, such as exceeding the maximum capacity of a single document, or losing the ability to query in the way that needed by your UI.  These problems are more expensive than document reads.